# Is there an API for this?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I know about [user_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) API. I've written a module that should display some information only if the user has specific rights on the taxonomy.

To be more precise:

- we've created a vocabulary, say `books`.
- in this vocabulary `books` we have a lot of terms, say for example `children` and `cooking`
- we've created roles *according to the terms*, i.e. roles like `role for children` and `role for cooking` => one role = one term.
- now I've written a module that should diplay a link to 'edit' or 'create' **only** if the user is logged, **and** if he has the rights based on the role (which heavily relies on the [taxonomy access rights](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access)).

In short: in my `node_view` hook:

- I have to check if it's a node with `books` vocabulary.
- if so, I have to read the associated term (there can be only one), let's take an example: `children`
- if the user is logged in **and** has the permissions of editing nodes with the specific term (`children` here), the I display a text with a link like `edit this book` and another like like `create a children's book`.

This is only the last part that is a problem to me.

Does the [user access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) API call works flawlessly, and takes in account those rights, or do I have some specific calls to do? No API seems available for the taxonomy access control (TAC).

Maybe you have an example somewhere (didn't find one actually)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually having a problem with user_access or just asking before you're trying it? I'm not really following what exactly is your problem.

Taxonomy Access Control should influence what user_access returns. Or you could just set permissions for "Use contextual links" and let Drupal take care of it with contextual links instead of writing a custom module.

Comment: I'm having a problem with `user_access` because it doesn't go "deep" enough for permissions, and I need to know whether user has rights to edit/create **plus** the rights to edit create the specific node regarding its terms *and* the rights given to the user through the api taxonomy access rights

Comment: Sorry I didn't read carefully the notes at the bottom of the TAC module. Now it works. I write your answer as  the good one. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you solved it.